# Chi square test for decision tree - formula meaning

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, data-mining

I can understand higher the value of chi square more significant is the split, but cannot understand the formula used. Please explain intuitively.

Comment: The formula in your question appears to be wrong -- that is not a chi-square statistic. Can you give a source for the formula?

Comment: This is not a chi-square formula. The question is invalid.

Comment: @Glen_b http://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/chi-square/

Comment: @Siv the formula in your question doesn't seem to be anywhere on that page that I can see. The nearest thing I can see to what you have is $\chi^2_c=\sum\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$ ... Yours contains a power of $\frac12$ that is not in that one, nor the other formulas I can see. Can you be more specific about where you want me to look or offer an alternative link? It still appears to be an error if it's meant to be distributed as chi-squared, but perhaps there's some use for it which we might be able to discern, given more context.

Comment: Okay may be the formula in question represents chi and not chi^2 @Glen_b. But I don't understand why we use such a measure in the sense the inner meaning of the formula

Comment: It can't be chi either.  That would have a square root over the entire summation, not over the individual terms in the sum. What you have is a sum of absolute Pearson residuals for a Poisson model, but it's not clear why you'd do that. Your question won't be answered in its present state. What is it you mean to ask? Please edit your question.

Comment: @Glen_b edited the question

Comment: Are you talking about a split for a binary tree only, or are you talking about an feature with more than two levels? Are you referring to the chi-square pruning described on p21 of [this pdf](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/273ASpring10/recitation4_decision_tree.pdf) or the ranking of categorical variables for split selection as described on p826 (12 page of the pdf) in [this paper](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A7n41.pdf) or something else? You really need to be more help in making it clear what you're asking about and what you need